# Does this code give the standard error or the standard deviation of a distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Wikipedia says "the relationship between the standard error and the standard deviation is such that, for a given sample size, the standard error equals the standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size." 
At [Standard errors for maximum likelihood estimates in FindDistributionParameters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/standard-errors-for-maximum-likelihood-estimates-in-finddistributionparameters/6507#6507), there is this code:

```
standarderrors[data_, dist_, paramlist_, mleRule_] := 
 Block[{len, infmat, cov},
  len = Length[data];
  (* compute negative of expected Fisher information *)
  infmat = -D[LogLikelihood[dist, data], {paramlist, 2}]/len /. mleRule;
  (* invert to get asymptotic covariance for Sqrt[n](theta-theta0) *)
  cov = Inverse[infmat];
  (* standard errors are the Sqrt of diagonal elements divided by sample size *)
  Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]/len]
 ]
```

which suggests it gives the Standard Error. But in the same link, the above code is later referred to as giving the Standard Deviation. Which is it?

Comment: Maybe to add more confusion:  standard errors are standard deviations.  But to your question:  that code produces the proper measure of precision for the parameter estimators.  (Although the use of the term `len` in that code can be completely removed and you'll get the same results.)

Comment: When you say "...the proper measure of precision for the parameter estimators," do you mean "the one sigma standard deviations for the fit values?"

Comment: You get an estimate of the standard error for each parameter estimate.

Comment: I am still confused. Wikipedia says standard errors are not standard deviations. Why do you say standard errors are standard deviations?

Comment: I believe you.  The first line in the Wikipedia for "standard error" is:  "The standard error (SE) of a parameter is the standard deviation of its sampling distribution."